# How to make a piece of a pie chart change color upon clicking it?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, plotting

I am trying to use the `EventHandler` and have managed to make the text change color upon clicking it, but cannot seem to make each piece of the pie chart change color as I click it. For the text I used this:

```
f[text_] := DynamicModule[{col = Red}, 
  EventHandler[Style[text, FontColor ->  Dynamic[col]], 
               {"MouseClicked" :> (col = col /. {Red-> Green, Green-> Blue, 
                                   Blue-> Red})}]]
```

When I apply this function `f` in the pie chart as follows:

```
PieChart[{{
   Labeled[.5, Style[f["A"], Bold]],
   Labeled[.5, Style[f["B"], Bold]]
   }, {
   Labeled[Style[.5, White], Style[f["C"], Bold]]
   }
  }]
```

it works.

How can I make the pieces of the pie change color upon clicking them?

Comment: Avoid using uppercase one-letter symbols as many of them (`E`, `I`, ...) have built-in meaning. Better stick to longer names or lowercase characters.

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, the `Dynamic` has to wrap the whole chart, it won't work inside the chart sector as e.g. `Button[Style[.7, Dynamic@c], ...]`:

```
c = Yellow;
Dynamic@PieChart[{
   {Labeled[.5, f@"AAA"], Labeled[.5, f@"BBB"]},
   {Labeled[.3, f@"CCC"], 
    Button[Style[.7, c], 
     c = c /. {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Green, Green -> Yellow, Yellow -> Red}]}
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]